# Who does Roland mean when he says “He said he didn’t need it”?

Tags: the-matrix

From his ship in *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Roland contacts Mauser:

> Roland: Finished loading ammunition?
>
> Mauser: Just about.
>
> Roland: Let's move it. We are out of time.

While piloting his ship, Niobe asks Roland:

> Niobe: You're not leaving them anything?
>
> Roland: **He** said **he** didn't need it.

Who exactly is "he" here?

Comment: I do wish people would stop downvoting these. It's fairly clear that OP is having some difficulty identifying who's being referred to in various scenes (typically where they relate to someone who's off-screen or in relation to conversations that happened in earlier films) and asking questions about these are perfectly well on-topic

Comment: It's also fairly clear that there's a basic lack of research.

Comment: And some of the titles aren’t great for searchability.

Comment: @Valorum Questions like this don’t seem to be about SF&F to me. Instead they strike me as belonging on ELL.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Our very strong concensus is that they're firmly on-topic. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11627/20774

Comment: @Valorum To me, a downvote is very different from a vote to close. The linked meta is about close votes, your first comment and my response are about downvotes. My thinking is downvotes are subjective and reflect opinions on the question. They are not affected by meta discussions. Asking people not to downvote is kinda like asking them not to vote at all, which I feel is against the while point of SE. There are no close votes on this question.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - If you're using your downvote to indicate '*I don't like **this kind** of question'*, that feels abusive and unfriendly. People had their opportunity to oppose them on the Meta question and lost.

Comment: @Valorum I use my downvotes to indicate that the question does not show any research effort and/or is unclear and/or is not useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"He" is ***Neo***. Niobe and Roland relay the substance of their (unseen) conversation with him to the Council in a later scene.

> **HAMMAN:** *And the Oracle said nothing of this?*
>
> **NIOBE:** *She told me that Neo would need my help
> and that when the time came, I would
> choose to help him or not.*
>
> **WEST:** *But what hope can a single vessel have
> against their entire defense system?*
>
> **ROLAND:** *None. It's completely impossible. But he
> wouldn't listen. **He wouldn't even take
> any ammunition.** He was totally out of his
> goddamn mind.*
>
> <sub><sup>Matrix Revolutions: Screenplay</sup></sub>